# 500 (Internal Server Error) - User Registration System - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So, basically I tried to create a user registration system in Laravel. The registration form validation works well, but after the validation passes I can't insert the data. Instead, I got this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried to use query builder to insert the data. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

**register-script.js**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnRegister').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/validate-register",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                email: $('#exampleInputEmail1').val(),
                username: $('#exampleInputUsername1').val(),
                password: $('#exampleInputPassword1').val(),
                confirmPassword: $('#exampleInputConfPassword1').val()
            },
            error: function (data) {
                var errMsg = "";
                var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                Object.keys(response.errors).forEach(function(k){
                    errMsg += '<li>' + response.errors[k] + '</li>'
                }) ;
                $('body').css({'overflow': 'visible'});
                $('.alert').css({'display': 'block'});
                $('.alert-danger').html(errMsg);
            },
            success:function(data){
                window.location.href = '/';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**register-controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\UserModel;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(){
        return view('register');
    }

    public function ValidateRegister(Request $req){

        $validatedData = $req->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'confirmPassword' => 'required|same:password'
        ]);   
        if(!$validatedData->fails())
            insertNewUser($validatedData['email'],$validatedData['username'],Hash::make($validatedData['password']));
    }

    public function insertNewUser($email, $username, $password){        
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'email' => $email,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ]);

        return response()->json(['response' => 'success']);
    }
}
```

Error messages:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/validate-register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Object.error (register-script.js:22)
    at u (app.js:1)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (app.js:1)
    at C (app.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
```

Comment: What does it say in your Laravel logs?  I imagine it gives you a more specific error to go with that 500 response.

Comment: @matticustard nothing specific in the logs though.

Comment: What about inspecting the network response in your browser's developer tools?  Does it return success if you comment out the database insert?

Comment: I do see a problem, but it shouldn't create a 500 error.  You need to `return` the `insertNewUser` or you'll never see the expected JSON response.

Comment: this is not a 500 but a javascript failure atleast what he posted

Comment: @mrhn: Please take another look.  It clearly indicates `500 (Internal Server Error)`.  The JavaScript error is a secondary issue in which they are attempting to use the `error` response as an object when it is `undefined or null`.

Comment: then post the 500 error? that is the javascript failing, look in storage/logs

Comment: in the error log it says:

Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\insertNewUser() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined function App\\Http\\Controllers\\insertNewUser() at C:\\Users\\STANLEY\\Desktop\\crud\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\RegisterController.php:26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try but I think that when you use `$request->validate([rules...])` it doesn't return a validator object, but instead the fields that have been validated as an array.

So you controller method should become:

```php
public function ValidateRegister(Request $req)
{
    $validatedData = $req->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'confirmPassword' => 'required|same:password'
    ]);

    return $this->insertNewUser(
        $validatedData['email'],
        $validatedData['username'],
        Hash::make($validatedData['password'])
    );
}
```

The validate method itself takes care of failed validation by returning the errors as a response

Comment: nevermind, i missed $this keyword when returning the `insertNewUser` function.